# Docker cannot run image due to a “hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call”

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, windows-container, .net-4.8

I wrote the following multi-stage build in a Dockerfile to both build and run an image for a **.NET Framework** console application:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN nuget restore MySolution.sln
WORKDIR /app/MyProject
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU
RUN echo $(ls ./)

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS runtime
WORKDIR /output
COPY --from=build /app/MyProject/bin .
RUN echo $(ls ./)
ENTRYPOINT ["MyProject.exe"]
```

So far, so good and Docker builds the image. However, when I run it inside a container, Docker fails with the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 75c0daf4796521dbb38016148a145d6b6bc70fb7cd3931e5c0c5c1232d972329 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF7CE419F4B: (caller: 00007FF7CE3CE13A) Exception(2) tid(390) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

I think the error is due to the fact that the second stage of the Dockerfile isn’t doing what it should be. In fact, when the parser arrives to the first `RUN echo $(ls ./)`, it correctly prints out the list of items included in the `/app/ProjectFolder` folder, with the `bin` and `obj` folders created by the build process (that is, the first stage of the Dockerfile). However, the second `RUN echo $(ls ./)` command just prints out this:

```
...
Step 12/13 : RUN echo $(ls ./)
 ---> Running in 1822187d8a21
$(ls ./)
...
```

So, it doesn’t even find the `MyProject.exe` file to be executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to build your application before to get the dll (msbuild step) on the bin folders. And then docker build again.